# Set parent controller for angular-ui modal

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui, angular-controller, angular-ui-modal

For this question a drawing is more explicative than words.
[image]

**Note**: the 2 blocks represent different modules. The drawn hierarchy comes from how I setup the application templates and ui-router.

I am trying to create a ui-modal instance from the `Ctrl2` controller, and I would like to use `Ctrl4` as the controller for the modal but also using `Ctrl3` as the parent scope in order to respect the chosen hierarchy of my application.

I'm having trouble with setting up the parent scope.

The ui-modal [api](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal) provides a `scope` options we can pass when creating the modal, this is indeed the parent scope.

This did not work:

```
var modalLoginInstance = $uibModal.open({
  animation: true,
  templateUrl: 'modal.html',
  controller: 'Ctrl4',
  size: size,
  scope: $controller('Ctrl3');
});
```

**My question is**: how can I set `Ctrl3` as the parent scope for the modal in order to respect the hierarchy and prototype inheritance between Ctrl4 and Ctrl3 (that is ultimately what I really need)?

Comment: Personally I would say you are looking at this from the wrong angle. Use service(s) to connect the controller models together

Comment: For example I have apps that share same modals across various controllers and for those i create my own modal service with functions that wrap `$uibModal.open`. Then I can pass in data models from other services as arguments as well as things like settings options. It removes need for controller coupling and cuts down duplication of calling `$uibModal.open` in numerous controllers...call a simple `myModalService` method instead

Comment: In this case I'm not looking to reuse scope models, I'm looking for common scope functions defined in Ctrl3 that otherwise I would have to duplicate in Ctrl4 (and so modal) and other parts of the "Ctrl3" hierarchy.

Comment: OK but functions can also be shared in services and are also considered part of models. Without more specifics it's hard to help from your diagram other than the connectors are usually services, not trying to force controllers to fit into parents-especially when that doesn't work within layouts